# Forking code compiles but gives error during execution

Tags: c, linux, process

Code compiles but don't run  and gives error at line 7 and line 10. I am unable to correct the errors, so please help me.
The following are the error sequence in the shell:

```
./mylab3.c: line 7: char: command not found
./mylab3.c: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./mylab3.c: line 10: `int main( )
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


char  *env_init[]= { "USER=unknown", "PATH=/tmp",NULL};


int main( )
{
    pid_t pid;
    int flag, status;
// Create child process #1
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0 )
    {
        perror( "fork error" );
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
// Child process – replace with different program
        flag = execle( "/bin/Is", "Is", "-IF",NULL,env_init);
        if (flag < 0)
        {
            perror( "execle error" );
        }
    }
    else
    {

        if (wait( &status ) != pid)
        {
            perror( "wait error" );
        }
    }
//Create child process #2
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        perror ( "fork error" );
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {

        flag = execlp( "./lab03script","lab03.script","file1", "file2", NULL);
        if (flag < 0)
        {
            perror( "execlp error" );
        }

    }
    else
    {

        if (wait( &status ) != pid)
        {
            perror( "wait error") ;
        }
    }
    exit ( 0 );
}
```

Comment: `./mylab3.c`?? Are you trying to run the C file directly? Please show exactly how you compiled and ran the program.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: You need to compile the source into executable and run the executable, not the source

Answer (score -2):

Change

```
char  *env_init[]= { "USER=unknown", "PATH=/tmp",NULL};
```

to

```
const char  *env_init[]= { "USER=unknown", "PATH=/tmp",NULL};
```

Convert a string to char* is deprecated.

Comment: Answer is irrelevant

Comment: @qrdl No, this is not irrelevant because if you use a compiler with a version where this "deprecate" syntax is not contemplated, you will get an error and perhaps you will know why. Irrelevant is saying things not related with the code or about the coding style or something like that.

Comment: Do error messages, posted by OP, indicate that the problem is with constness? And cast from non-const to const is implicit, so your answer is irrelevant and plain wrong. BTW what do you mean by string? There is no such type in C.